# CreateFile in Kernel32.dll does not allow me to open a physical disk

Tags: c#, .net, windows, pinvoke, kernel32

I am trying to use the following code to get the **MBR** from `PhysicalDrive0`:

```
private static byte[] ReadMbr(string lpFileName)
{
   byte[] mbr = new byte[512];

   using (SafeFileHandle drive = CreateFile(
         lpFileName: lpFileName,
         dwDesiredAccess: (uint) EFileAccess.GenericRead, //DO NOT MODIFY THE MBR!!!
         dwShareMode: (uint)EFileShare.Write | (uint)EFileShare.Read | (uint)EFileShare.Delete,
         SecurityAttributes: IntPtr.Zero,
         dwCreationDisposition: (uint) ECreationDisposition.OpenAlways,
         dwFlagsAndAttributes: (uint)EFileAttributes.System,
         hTemplateFile: IntPtr.Zero))
   {
      if (drive.IsInvalid)
         throw new IOException("Unable to access drive. Win32 Error Code " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

      //Get the 1st 512 bytes of the volume (MBR)
      using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(drive, FileAccess.Read))
      {
         stream.Read(mbr, 0, 512);
      }
   }

   return mbr;
}
```

I have tried passing

- `\\.\PhysicalDisk0`
- `\\.\PhysicalDrive0`
- `\\.\PhysicalDisk0:`
- `\\.\PhysicalDrive0`

and none of them work. I am running it as administrator. I can also get `\\.\C:` to work and display the VBR without any issues.

For the record:

-I am running Windows Server 2008 R2.

### References

- MSDN: [CreateFile function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28VS.85%29.aspx)
- MSDN: [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: What's the Win32 error code you receive?

Comment: It was giving me a 2 and an 87 depending on what input I was using.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [CreateFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28VS.85%29.aspx) documentation:

> The following requirements must be met
>   for such a call to succeed:
>
> - The caller must have administrative privileges. For more
>     information, see *Running with Special
>     Privileges*.
> - **The `dwCreationDisposition` parameter must have the
>     `OPEN_EXISTING` flag**.
> - When opening a volume or floppy disk, the `dwShareMode` parameter must
>     have the `FILE_SHARE_WRITE` flag.

You might want to try passing `ECreationDisposition.OpenExisting` in `dwCreationDisposition`.

Comment: This was the ticket! Thank you so much!